# How to check if my EKS container runtime is docker (for k8s 1.24 update)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-eks

I'm planning on updating my EKS to version 1.24 and I'm trying to understand whether my nodes are using the Docker runtime as it is no longer supported from 1.24

I've found [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/migrating-from-dockershim/find-out-runtime-you-use/#find-out-the-container-runtime-used-on-a-node) link and saw that my container runtime is Docker but it is stated that even if Docker is used - you still need to check your container runtime endpoint by following the instructions [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/migrating-from-dockershim/find-out-runtime-you-use/#which-endpoint).

I couldn't really understand where those commands need to run so I kept on searching info online and found some contradicting statements.

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/amazon-eks-1-21-released/) it is mentioned that containerd will be the default runtime since EKS 1.23 but [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/dockershim-deprecation.html) it looks like it will be the default only from 1.24

What I'm trying to understand is whether I am using the Docker runtime which means I might need to make some changes. I'm already on EKS 1.23 with the latest AMIs.

Comment: Practically, it should almost never matter, the operation of standard Kubernetes objects like Deployments doesn't change.  Why would you need to know?

Comment: It is mentioned that nodes should be migrated to the containerd runtime before moving to 1.24

Answer (score 0):

> ...you still need to check your container runtime endpoint by following the instructions here...
> I couldn't really understand where those commands need to run

The command is to run on the worker node (EC2 instance). You can use SSH to login and execute the command to affirm the container runtime engine in used.

Comment: All I found is that my runtime shows as Docker Engine but it is stated that I still might not be affected by the removal of dockershim in k8s 1.24 in case my runtime endpoint doesn't use it.
The question is what if it is? Do I have to manually perform some kind of change / migration? Sounds like something that I would expect EKS to take care of for me.

Comment: No, you do not need to manually perform any kind of change pertain to the endpoint.